# Error:Missing Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

I have created my own framework which has Tabbars.While Implementing on another program it gives`Error` as Follows:

```
ld: framework not found OwnTabFramework
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm struggling for 2 days.Can anyBody help me findout where i've done wrong.or how to solve this kind of error.?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the framework into the compilation process. From Xcode Build-Setting->SearchPAth->Framework-Search-Path.

or a simple example by command line:

```
clang main.c -F /frameworkPath../ -framework MyFramework
```

Because the linker will not find it magically ;)

Answer (score 0):

add it to the project and it is put into linked frameworks just like the apple ones

[image]
[image]